# Increase workspace sizes in Papyrus

Tags: eclipse, sequence-diagram, papyrus

I try to stretch this sequence diagram (titled `Interaction11`) to place more elements on it, but the program does not let me do it. How can I edit the size of the diagram? (Remark: it's Eclipse Oxygen 4.9.2)[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is probably a bug on this feature.

My workarounds:

- If you want to increase the horizontal size of the diagram, just add a lifeline and drag it to the side of the diagram.
- If you want to increase the vertical size of the diagram, my workaround is to open the *.notation file of the Papyrus model and to change manually the "layoutConstraint" of a lifeline.

---

For example: 
`<layoutConstraint xmi:type="notation:Bounds" xmi:id="_Qom6FgLWEemGgOZiGDqIUw" x="74" y="10" height="4000"/>`

Regards.

Yoann.